# What are the demons at the end of Madoka Magica?

Tags: madoka-magica

What are the demon-like entities shown at end of *Madoka Magica*, which Homura is now fighting instead of witches?

And what does Homura's explanation mean, regarding how these demons replaced witches?

Comment: It was kinda all "buried" in Madoka's wish. Though I'd also be interested in the details.

Comment: I think the best way to answer this question is to wait for movie 3 to come out, which is supposed to be after the events of the TV series. Then it will be (hopefully) clear.

Comment: @LoganM from what i heard the first movie rehashes the story and the second does as well however ends differently than the anime which then leads into the third movie

Comment: @Memor-X It's been a while since I've seen the movie (watched it in the initial theater run) so I could be mis-remembering, but I remember the ending of the second movie being quite similar to the TV version. There was a PV for the third movie after the end of the second movie, which could be the differences you're talking about.

Comment: @LoganM i'm just going off what i read originally based from the fact that it would be weird to rehash the series in 2 movies unless the second movie deviated from where the first ended, i brought the Import Limited Edition of the first 2 movies just in case it never gets dubbed, i haven't watch the movies yet as i'm going to do the same as i did with Fate/Zero and wait about a year to see if they do get Dubbed, i take preference on Dubbed over Subbed because i'm still not used to reading the subtitles while watching the anime, also,

Comment: @Memor-X The movies end same as TV series.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

During the conversation between Kyubey and Homura near the end of the final episode of the series, Homura mentions that although Madoka's wish prevented witches from being born, the curses from the human world still remained and continue to haunt humanity in the form of "magical beasts" (魔獣), which are demonic forces of unknown nature.

The new role of magical girls now is to defeat these demons, gather their curses in the forms of small cube fragments, and have Kyubey harvest them, in order to slow the effects of entropy on the universe.

Comment: I'm quite sure that they are refereed to as "Wraiths"